# In a DWARF file, what's the difference between .debug_str and .strtab?

Tags: elf, dwarf

I'm working with [DWARF parser](https://github.com/csholmq/ElfParser) that looks for string data in the `.debug_str` section. In the ELF files I'm parsing, the string data is in the `.strtab` section. What's the difference between these two sections? Both contain strings, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the difference between these two sections?

They have ~nothing to do with each other.

> Both contain strings, right?

Well, yes. And *every* section contains bytes, so next you'll be asking "what's the difference between `.text` and `.data`?".

The `.debug_str` section contains debug strings, which are needed for debugging.
The `.strtab` section contains symbol names which are needed for (static) linking.

Neither section (in fact *no* section) is needed at runtime.

> why .strtab is present in final executable linked with -g (even though it won't be used for static linking anymore)?

1. The `.strtab` is usually present in final executable built with or *without* `-g` and
2. It's present to help with debugging. Consider:

```
int foo() { abort(); }
int bar() { return foo(); }
int main() { return bar(); }

gcc t.c
strip a.out -o a.stripped

gdb -q ./a.stripped
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.stripped

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a4bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7a4f028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x0000000000400536 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000400544 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000400554 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffff7a36f45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x400546, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde58, init=, fini=, rtld_fini=, stack_end=0x7fffffffde48) at libc-start.c:287
#6  0x0000000000400469 in ?? ()
```

Not very useful, is it? Compare to unstripped binary:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a4bc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7a4f028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x0000000000400536 in foo ()
#3  0x0000000000400544 in bar ()
#4  0x0000000000400554 in main ()
```

Comment: For completeness, why .strtab is present in final executable linked with `-g` (even though it won't be used for static linking anymore)?